# CE Cache pre - sales questions

Tags: ce-cache

Three questions:

1. I see a lot of unanswered questions in here on CE Cache - is the add on still being supported / used?
2. I want to use CE-Cache for pages that look at incoming variables (like segment, and embed) and cache the resulting version of the page based on those.  For example:

embed variable - area = 1

I want to cache a version of the resulting template as "1", "2", etc. to match the incoming value of area.  So a page that is normally dynamic for each person's area, would pull up the right cached version of the page.  Can CE Cache do that?

3. I to use PHP on output in some of my templates - can CE Cache work with that? Or will that not get parsed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to answer this, as I bought the plugin:

1. Not sure if it's still supported.
2. I was able to use segment / embed variables to specify unique cache names, so I could cache part / all of a template to a unique ID based on the specific incoming url. That was perfect for my purposes
3. the php does not get parsed but is part of the cached file.  So you see all the EE code / queries are parsed and executed, but the php is still parsed last.  Still, this seems to speed things up pretty much, at least in my case.  The EE queries seem to be the biggest resource hogs.

One thing I did notice was that some "layout" variables didn't like being inside the cache tags, but I didn't investigate enough to see if there's a workaround.  I didn't need to cache those.

Anyway, the plugin works well for my application, I suspect most sites would gain something by using it.

-jim